# MySQL match against works only if I match one column

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make work this query (since hours...), but I can't figure out what's wrong:

```
SELECT title,text, MATCH(title,text) AGAINST ('".$key."') AS score 
FROM ml_products WHERE MATCH(title,text) AGAINST ('".$key."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

By the way it works if I match only title (or only text), for example like this:

```
SELECT title,text, MATCH(title) AGAINST ('".$key."') AS score 
FROM ml_products WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST ('".$key."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Both title and text are FULLTEXT key

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ml_products` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_prod` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ml_code` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(86) NOT NULL,
  `text` text NOT NULL,
  `descr` varchar(180) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=570 ;
```

What could be the reason why it works only in the second case?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You say both have a FULLTEXT key, but does the combination of the two have a compound FULLTEXT key? Please post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE ml_products` so we can see the table definition.

Comment: As I suspected - looks like you will need a compound index across both columns.  `ALTER TABLE ml_products ADD FULLTEXT KEY (title,text)`

Comment: _The MATCH() column list must match exactly the column list in some FULLTEXT index definition for the table_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html